# How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, application-settings

How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form (settings.form)? I want to develop my graduation project. Its a social media desktop management project. I want to change all of the forms to dark mode with one switcher. How can I do that? This my settings.cs

```
public void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        panel1.BackColor= Color.FromArgb(34, 36, 49);
        form1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(34, 36, 49);
        form2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(34, 36, 49);
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(34, 36, 49);
        this.label1.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(34, 36, 49);
    }
    else
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.label1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(34, 36, 49);
        this.label1.ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    form1.Show();
    form1.Refresh();
    form2.Show();
    form2.Refresh();
```

All background color is changing when I switch. But all forms is opening sametime.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Which part does your code fail to achieve?

Comment: I want to change all of forms background color from one form. For example: In form1 when i press the settings button opens form3(settingsform) and swich to color to dark mode. When i do that all forms are opening form1,form2,form3. And old forms are open too. I want to do like phones dark modes. when u press the button all phone switching to dark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `(ApplicationSettings)` property, accessible from the Form Designer's `Properties` panel. Expand `ApplicationSettings`, open up the `PropertyBinding` dialog, add a Setting to the `BackColor` property (e.g., `CommonFormBackColor`) and use the same setting for all Forms.

You can create the Setting directly in the Application Settings' `PropertyBinding` dialog:

[image: Properties Application Settings New]

This new Setting is created in the User Scope.
All settings in the User Scope are applied on a per-User basis and can be changed.
Settings in the Application Scope are considered read-only.

[image: Properties Application Settings Add]

The new Setting will then appear under the `ApplicationSettings` expandable property:

[image: Properties Application Settings]

Assign the same Setting to all Forms that should change their BackColor when this setting is changed.
You can of course assign a common Setting to any other Property of any other Control.

The use of a [Form Template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/design-time-code-generation-by-using-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019) (or a base Form class) can automate the whole process.

When the Setting value is changed at run-time, all opened Forms - and those that will be opened later - will present the same `BackColor`.

You can set a new value to all Form's BackColor changing the Settings's Value:
<sub>(all opened Form that share the same Setting for the `BackGround` Color will change color immediately)</sub>

```
Properties.Settings.Default.CommonFormBackColor = Color.Orange;
```

You can save the current Settings selection (to preserve the value assigned in the current *session*, so it will be used again when the application is restarted) with:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

You can reset the default value (the value originally assigned to the Settings in the Designer) calling:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reset();
```