# Update a value on every form if changed in one

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am trying to change one label onto multiple forms. The label updates during changes on one form but it must be linked to the label to the other forms. Meaning if label1 on form 1 displays 10 and I go to form 2 it must also display 10 label2. If the label gets updated to 11 on form 2 and I go back to form 1 it must display 11. I have never done this before and can't figure out any coding to get this. Is there a way to do this?

form 1

form2 frm2 = new form2();
            frm2.LabelText = this.button1.Text;

form2

public string LabelText
        {
            get
            {
                return this.totalChips.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                this.totalChips.Text = value;
            }
        }

Comment: Show us what you've tried, so we can put you on the right track.

Comment: See the simple method here: [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103), which of course applies to any other property of any other control, using a single setting.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if u want to take form1's label1's text from other form.
First make label1 public from form1's Designer.cs.
Then : (Also it works in static methods too)

```
string label1text = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Last()?.label1.Text;
```

There is probably more efficient way but thats what i know.
Sorry for bad english btw.

Comment: You think that `Last()?.label1.Text` contains a label1 property?

Answer (score 0):

I would pass an object to the constructor. The object containing some properties and when the property is set, it will fire an event to all the listeners, which then can update their screen. The advantage of this method is, is that Form2 is not dependend on Form1 (decoupled). The Form2 is still reusable to use by, for example, Form3, as long as the caller passes a valid DataObject.

Here is an example how to use the INotifyPropertyChanged

```
I have 2 forms.
- form1 has a TextBox and two buttons (one is Set Title property, the other is open form2)
- form2 has a Label, which is only showing the property.

So form1 set the property of the data object, form2 listens to the propertychanged event.
```

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly DataObject _dataObject = new DataObject();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // pass the DataObject into the constructor.
        var form2 = new Form2(_dataObject);
        form2.Show();
    }

    private void buttonSetTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _dataObject.Title = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private DataObject _dataObject;

    // here the dataobject is passed to this form
    public Form2(DataObject dataObject)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dataObject = dataObject;
        _dataObject.PropertyChanged += DataObject_PropertyChanged;

        // deregister the event on close
        FormClosed += (s, ee) => _dataObject.PropertyChanged -= DataObject_PropertyChanged;

        UpdateTitle();
    }

    // a method responsible for updating the gui.
    private void UpdateTitle() =>
        label1.Text = _dataObject.Title;

    private void DataObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(DataObject.Title):
                UpdateTitle();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class DataObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            // here the event is fired.
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Title)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Okay I managed I managed to connect the labels using with an simple passing method. But now I want to convert the text from the label to int to later substract numbers from it. I tried convert.ToInt32() and parse. I declared the int in the page load but cant use it in another class

Comment: Before I could declare the int at the top but it was set as int x = 1000; now I want the labels value to display as the int value