# VB.NET Link Label to another Label

Tags: vb.net, text, binding, label

I am new to VB.NET and also am self taught, so basically I know nothing. I have written some software (~2000 lines) it is fairly basic. However many of those lines are just changing different labels (on different tabs) when the user does different things.

I find modifying labels to be very annoying, mostly when I have 3-4 labels that always show the same thing but in different places. I have done some searching related to trying to link or bind these labels but I don't think I have found what I am looking for. I'm sure I am searching the wrong terminology or something very simple.

My question is: Is there a simple way to link labels together so I only need to change text/color on one label and the other "linked" labels follow suit?

Below is a snippet of what I am trying to simplify.

```
            lblStatus.Text = "Connected to transmitter!"
            lblStatus.BackColor = Color.Green
            lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.White
            lblRadioStatus.Text = "Connected to transmitter!"
            lblRadioStatus.BackColor = Color.Green
            lblRadioStatus.ForeColor = Color.White
            lblStatusRec.Text = "Connected to transmitter!"
            lblStatusRec.BackColor = Color.Green
            lblStatusRec.ForeColor = Color.White
            lblRadioSetup.Text = "Connected to transmitter!"
            lblRadioSetup.BackColor = Color.Green
            lblRadioSetup.ForeColor = Color.White
```

These labels always show the same but are displayed on different tabs. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Follow the procedure explained here: [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of labels declared at the form level and then fill this array after the call to InitializeComponent with the labels that you want to change.

Then write a method that loops over the array and change all the labels with your values.

For example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim myLabels() As Label
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        myLabels = New Label() {lblStatus, lblStatusRec, lblRadioStatus, lblRadioSetup};
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateLabel(labelText As String, fore As Color, back As Color)
       For Each lbl In myLabels
            l.Text = labelText
            l.BackColor = back
            l.ForeColor = fore
       Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Now, everytime you need to change these labels you call the UpdateLabel method with the parameters required.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I don't know why had not thought of adding them to an array. I will give that I shot and see how I like it. In the meantime I will wait and see if someone has another suggestion for curiosity sake.

Comment: Please try and provide a vb.net answer to a vb.net question. C# may or may not be comprehensible to the OP and future readers.

Comment: @Mary corrected now. Sometime my mind is so fixed on the current work to fail to notice the things under my nose