# C# Save default Text Box Text

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, save, richtextbox

I want to save default Text Box.

I already created a code which saves the text box text. For example if u write something in it and close, it will be saved when another time opening. But, if i type in Visual Studio the Text Box default text for example "Hi", i open the form, and it gives me nothing, just a blank text box. I Also tried to do it from Properties>Settings>TextBox>Value>Hi and still it's just a blank text box.

The two codes is:

Form1_Closed:

```
        Properties.Settings.Default.textbox = TextBox1.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Form1_Load:

```
        TextBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.textbox;
```

So how i can save the default text? For example, i write something in the text box, user downloads my application, and he can see the word "Hi" in the text box, but if he writes something in the text box, then it will save his text after closing too.

Comment: you dont need this code just set your textbox in one string like this code,string str= TextBox1.Text;

Comment: Follow the procedure described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103)