# how to drag and drop label to a new location and set that location as new location of the label using c# in windows form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms, winforms

Using my code I can drag and drop to new location, but when I close my windows form then the location is again reset to the old location. I want the label at its new position after drag and drop even is I close my form or stop debugging(stop execution)
Name of label: label1

CODE:
namespace EINS_FloorMap
{

```
public partial class EINS_FloorMap : Form
{

     clsConnection_DAL objCore = new clsConnection_DAL(true, true);

     

     private System.Drawing.Point StartPoint;
     private bool IsMouseDown = false;

    public EINS_FloorMap()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     }
    private void label1_MouseDown_1(object sender, 
                             System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            IsMouseDown = true;
            label1.BringToFront();
            StartPoint = e.Location;
        }
     }
    private void label1_MouseUp_1(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseDown = false;

        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(
            this.label1.Location.X,this.label1.Location.Y
            );
    }
     private void label1_MouseMove_1(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouseDown)
        {
            label1.Left = e.X + label1.Left - StartPoint.X;
            label1.Top = e.Y + label1.Top - StartPoint.Y;


        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103) to the `Location` Property of your Label. The setting is updated and save automatically. -- The `asp.net` tag use here is unclear. -- BTW, you can remove `IsMouseDown` and just check, in MouseMove, whether `e.Button == MouseButtons.Left`, as you're doing in MouseDown. Then also remove the MouseUp handler (which is really useless). -- Given the names of the event handlers, you probably have more than one handler there, so check that out.

Comment: this is Location Property of label1:                                                             this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13,97);                                                     Using my code I can drag and drop to new location, but when I close my windows form then the location of label1 is again reset to the old location. I want the label at its new position after drag and drop, even if I close my form or stop debugging(stop execution)

Comment: That's why I suggested to adopt the solution shown in that post. This is how you automatically store and restore the value of a Property.

Comment: please explain using example.

Comment: The whole procedure is explained, also with pictures, in [the post I linked before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103).