# How do I save the text in the Label when we close the app? (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, save

So, I have a simple countdown timer. It counts from 60 seconds. The interval of the timer is 1000, so it'll be a second. The code of it is:

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text - 1
    End Sub
```

So, how do I save the text in Label1? Like when it is 49 seconds, I close the app and now opens the app and it again starts from 49 seconds. But how do I do that?

With much better example of that:
If it countdowns from 60 seconds, and now it is 49 seconds, I close the app and open it and it should countdown from 49 seconds.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use PropertyBinding to bind the Text of your Control (and many other properties) to the ApplicationSettings, as described here: [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103) (read to the end). Otherwise, you'll have to store it to disc in a way or another: your own Settings file, a simple text file, `.ini file`, or JSON / XML format, a simple database etc. If you already store some settings in the Registry, that too.

Comment: @Jimi I didn't understand what you mean, or that's not what I wanted. Is there a way to save the text in Label in My.Settings? If yes, let me know, please! And yes, I want to save through the My.Settings. I don't want it to get saved as a file, I want to save the text in label and when we leave the app and open it should count from there. For example: It is 49 seconds and I leave the app and open it again and it should countdown again from 49 seconds. I hope you understand now, or maybe I didn't understand you.

Comment: Then follow the procedure described in the post I linked (reading **to the end**).

Comment: @Jimi So, there's no way to save it using My.Settings?

Comment: @Jimi Nevermind, I found my way to save it using My.Settings. But still thanks! :)

Comment: That's meant to save the Text in the Application Settings. It automates the procedure. Did you read that post?

Comment: @Jimi This is what I used: When form is closing, it saves it like this `My.Settings.TextSaver = Label1.Text` then when form loads, I used this `Label1.Text = My.Settings.TextSaver`. That's simple!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, to do it manually (w/out using PropertyBinding):

- In your project's Properties panel, go to the Settings tab
- Create the setting however you want it (i.e. give it a name, and type)
- In your code, wherever you need it do something like:

```
' Read the setting (in this case, assume it's a string):
Debug.Print(My.Settings.SettingName)

' Change the setting
My.Settings.SettingName = "Something else"
My.Settings.Save
```

To have the app continue from where you left it (as in your comment) you'll need to save it's current value before exiting; and then when starting up again read the setting and fill in the field with it.