# Change Backcolor for all inherited forms

Tags: vb.net, forms, oop, inheritance

i have a baseform and a few forms inherited from that.
Call them BaseForm and Form1, Form2
I want to select a color in Form1 and these color is set in all inherited forms.
That works, if the form is open after the color is changed.
Let me explain.
I open Form1
select the color and set a global variable(glColorVariable).
The Backgroundcolor in the Baseform.Designer.vb is set

```
me.backcolor=glColorVariable
```

The color in Form1 didn't change

If i now open form2 the color in form2 IS changed.

How can i ... repaint my Baseform in Form1 so the color is changed.
Thank you verry much!

Cornelia

Comment: Why don't you use PropetyBinding instead, to bind the BackColor to the value of a Setting, as described here: [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103). It works with all already opened Forms and all Forms that are opened after.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Perhaps because that's what i have looking for? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't loop forms so that you can change a parameter on them.
I think the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() is dead end for this.
One solution, if you fill an list element with your forms.

```
Dim Forms As New List(Of Form)
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Forms.Add(My.Forms.Form1)
    Forms.Add(My.Forms.Form2)
    Forms.Add(My.Forms.Form3)
End Sub
Sub SetBackColors(ByVal c As Color)
    For Each f In Forms
        f.BackColor = c
    Next
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SetBackColors(Color.Red)
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Form2.Show()
    Form3.Show()
End Sub
```

or what Jimi wrote, use DataBindings:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form2.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", Me, "BackColor", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
    Form3.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", Me, "BackColor", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Form2.Show()
    Form3.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your Answer, The Solution with the property binding works verry well.