# Enable/Disable button on next startup

Tags: c#, winforms, button, startup

I'm essentially trying to make it so that after I click a Button, said button would be disabled.
However, this Button should remain disabled when the application is restarted.

I currently can enable/disable the Button, but it's reset to `Enabled` upon restart.

Comment: Follow the procedure described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103) to bind the `Enabled` property.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! IT WORKS NOW