# C# how to permanently change form background?

Tags: c#, winforms, background, picturebox

I have this `Picturebox` and `Button` to upload my background picture from my desktop. It changes the background but opening my form again the previous image is still there and had not changed. Is there any method to change the background permanently?

this is my button:

```
            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                PictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
                Image newImage = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
                MainPage mp = (MainPage)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["MainPage"];
                mp.ChangeBackground(newImage);
            }
```

Comment: Create a Load() method in form and change  background in the Load() method or create a constructor in the form with a background color and change the background in the constructor.

Comment: [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103). In this case, you could store a string value that represents the path of the Image file. Or use the default image if the file is not there.

Comment: thanks! could you give me an example on how to create that method? @jdweng

Comment: Se : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?force_isolation=true&view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Tried doing this but I'm not sure how to properly save the picture. everytime i'm changing the background it does change but when I run the program again still the old picture. @jdweng

Comment: I am using a picturebox for my background do you have any other suggestions? @Jimi

Comment: It doesn't matter what Control show the Bitmap. You have an OpenFileDialog there: when you get the path of the image file, store it in the Project's Settings. When your Form is opened again, get the image file path from the Settings (check whether it's null and also whether the image file exists) and assign the Bitmap you load to whatever Control is meant to show it. Otherwise, show the default Bitmap (from the Project's Resources, I assume) or show nothing. -- The Q&A I linked shows how to implement this.

Comment: thanks I'll do it now. but what if it's an image and not a color? cause I couldn't find the Image option on PropertyBinding @Jimi

Comment: That shows how to use the Settings. Now you can bind a Property or just use a Setting as storage. In this case, you can store the image file path. When you get to data bindings, you can bind the Property of a class object and use it to set a Property of a Control when the class is initialized (or when a Property value is changed, or in any other scenario, depending on the implementation).  For now, just use a string.