# Getting values from my SQL database and applying them to the properties of my objects in C# window application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want users to be able to customize my software.
Please I want to be able to set the properties of all my objects in my C# program, by selecting from SQL database and applying as default for all my objects e.g, textbox, label, groupbox, etc. Thanks.

I already tried:

```cs
int HBColor=Convert. ToInt32(@myargbcolor);

Groupbox mygbox=new Groupbox();
mygbox.DefaultBackcolor=Color.FromArgb(HBColor);
```

Where `HBcolor` is the argb color selected from and converted to into. But it's telling me the `mygbox.DefaultBackcolor` must be at the left hand of the assignment `+=`.
Please help me to be able to set the properties of my objects.

Comment: I don't see any `+=`. Are you sure you are showing us the right code snippet? The C# compiler tells you the exact place in code where the problem occurs.

Comment: If `GroupBox` is a `System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox`, there's no `DefaultBackcolor` property. Try `BackColor`.

Comment: Please there's no BackColor either, I've tried that.

Comment: Of course that property is available, it belongs to the `Control` base class. -- What is `Groupbox`? The name of the class is `GroupBox` (capital `B`). Post your actual code, that would not compile.

Comment: Note that both `GroupBox` and `BackColor` are case-sensitive. 

If you include your code that defines / populates `@myargbcolor` that would help.

Comment: The @myargbcolor is a argb color I inserted into my database. Its valid I've tested it. But I don't know how to make the color the default backcolor of all my groupbox in the form.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me. We could give you more guidance if we knew what your SQL command looks like, but without that I took a guess.

```
int myArgbColor;

// this is a guess as to what your sql command looks like. adjust as necessary.
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("replace this with your connection string"))
{
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select @myargbcolor = ArgbColor from dbo.FormSettings;", sqlConnection);
    var myArgbcolorParam = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@myargbcolor", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
    myArgbcolorParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myArgbColor = int.Parse(myArgbcolorParam.Value.ToString());
    sqlConnection.Close();
};

// If you want to refer to an existing `GroupBox`  rather than instantate a new one. Use something like `this.mygbox = ...`.
GroupBox mygbox = new GroupBox();
mygbox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(myArgbColor);
```

Here it is in action:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I got the selection of the argb color from the database correctly, converted it to int data type successfully, converted it to color from agrb successfully too...but I can't seem to make it the default background color of all my group box in my form. I've tried the above method. Creating a new instance of Group box and assigning my color into it, it worked though, but it didn't make the color the default background color of all my group box in my form. It just created a new Groupbox object.

Comment: You can bind the `BackColor` property to `ApplicationSettings`, as described here: [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103) -- If you're targeting .Net 5+, the  `PropertyBinding` graphic interface is not yet available, the binding needs to be created in code *manually*.