# How set a variable the Properties.Settings.Default?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Properties files that store colors.

1. Properties.Green.Theme
2. Properties.PurpleTheme

The names of the parameters in the files are completely the same. I want to implement a theme change by switching between these two files. The simplest thing, in theory, is to assign a variable a value with a visibility level for the entire class. For example, var theme = Properties.GreenTheme.Default. And then use this variable in the methods. because the names are the same everywhere. Sample code in what form I want to do it:

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form{

TypeVar theme = null;

public FrmMain()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        if (i = 1)
        {
            theme = Properties.GreenTheme.Default;
        }

        if (i = 3)
        {
            theme = Properties.PurpleTheme.Default;
        }

        SetBottonColor();   
        SetPanelColor();

}

private void SetBottonColor()
{
    btn.BackColor = theme.button_color;
    btn2.BackColor = theme.button_color;
    btn3.BackColor = theme.button_color;
}

private void SetPanelColor()
{
   panel.BackColor = theme.panel_color;
   panel2.BackColor = theme.panel_color;
}
```

}

that is, in order not to prescribe if in each method, I want to create a variable at the class level and change it when loading the form. And since the names of the parameters in the files are the same, the colors would be taken from the desired file. Locally I can easily declare a variable

```
var theme = Properties.PurpleTheme.Default;
```

But I need it at the class level because there are a lot of such methods. object as var unfortunately does not work...

p.s. Sorry for my English

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. -- If you want to use Settings files to change the colors of your UI, you can bind the properties you want to change to a default Settings object that represent a *blank* Theme (all property settings set to `null`). Then set the property values of this base Settings object to the property values of one of the Settings Theme you select. This way, you can set the base Theme to any of the Theme Settings at any time, both when the application starts or at run-time, just replacing the `PropertyValues` collection of the base object with those of another.

Comment: Note that this method causes a *persistent behavior*: in case you don't set any Theme, the last one applied is restored at start up.  -- The *blank* Theme must never be saved. The other color Theme Settings can be modified instead and of course you can add others `Settings` files that represent different Color Themes.

Comment: An empty theme is just for example. The question is what type of variable (TypeVar) is in this place?
TypeVar theme = null;

Comment: The Setting Theme with null properties (not exactly *empty*) is the example that I made, because it's one of the methods I've used. It's the simples of all possible methods to use multiple Settings. This because a Setting is a class object that is auto-generated, so even if you define an Interface and apply the Interface to each class member (so your `VarType` would be, e.g., `IMySettings`), each time you modify something these class object are overwritten. So, you can make a Setting that has all the same properties but no values, then at run-time, you can copy the property values [...]

Comment: of the selected Setting over the *blank* Setting. Your `VarType` then becomes the Type of the *blank* Setting class and you pass this Type to the methods that assign the Color (you don't need a Field in the class scope at all). You could use a `Dictionary<int, SettingsBase>` to store your settings and select one specifying a Key (which is an `int`, as you have now) -- Note  that usually the Controls that should modify their aspect based on Settings, bind their proeprties to the `(ApplicationSettings)` (see the PropertyGrid).

Comment: This is an example of that functionality: [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103)

Comment: It's a good idea. I hadn't thought of that!!! Yes it will work! Thank you very much!