# Checkbox save state using settings not working (winforms C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

As you can see below, save code.
No errors at all.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vZHG.png)

But when I change the state of the checkbox and close the form, the setting does not update and remains false.

Yes I do have something that uses the setting, and that works normally.

Comment: Instead of *assigning* a value from the Settings, bind the `Checked` Property of your CheckBox (and/or different properties of other Controls) to the ApplicationSettings. You then just need to `Save()` the Settings when the Form closes and all changes to bound properties are restored when the Form is reopened. Follow the example here: [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103)

Comment: If you're targeting .Net 5+, the `ApplicationSettings` binding tool is still not working and has been removed from the PropertyGrid (there's only `(DataBindings)`), but you can add the binding in code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not following what the problem is. How are you “checking” if the setting is saved? In other words, I see nothing in your current code that actually USES the setting. I suggest you grab and apply the `Properties CheckBox` setting value to the `CheckBox ExampleToggle`  when the form loads. Something like…

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ExampleToggle.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox;
}
```

Also, in the future, posting pictures of code is frowned upon. You are forcing others who may help you into typing the code themselves. Many will just move on if they have to type the code.