# Styling a form and its components from a public class

Tags: c#, winforms

Windows Form Application. I want to format all forms and it's components (e.g. textboxes, datagrid, comboboxes, etc.) from a central class file. I'm trying to keep things tidy and code tidy so it's easy to replicate, modify and edit.

So let say I have 3 forms, all the properties have been set to public modifiers:

- Form1 with textbox, datagrid.
- Form2 with combobox, buttons, etc.
- Form3 with textbox, button and datagrid.

Now from a public class I want to change the look: colour, borders, font size, visibility, etc. for each form.

How do I do it? Is it possible?

```
namespace testapp
{
    public class Form1
    {
         BackColor = White;
         data_GridView.Visible = false;
         data_GridView.AutoResizeColumns();
    }
    public class Form2
    {
         BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
         button.BackColor = Transparent;
...
```

I can't call the different components from the public class. I don't know how, I have tried different things but it always gives me errors.

Comment: You could use ApplicationSettings, e.g., [How can we change the background color of all other forms from one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160815/7444103). Or build a base Form template (this is more complex)

Comment: Note that you don't need to use ApplicationSettings as the binder, you can use your own class object and bind Form properties to properties of your class. Using generics and some Interfaces, you can also determine different behaviors, based on the interfaces a class implements

Comment: Could you please provide more examples of doing the base Form Temple or own class object and bind Form properies? Please. Ultimately I want the user to be able to change the values. Thank you